# Usage of IHttpClientFactory disposes of context.RequiredService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

Have a look at this code:

```cs
public static class HttpClientExperimentExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddHttpClientExperiment(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient("client1", (serviceProvider, client) =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
            });
        services.AddScoped<Service1>();
        return services;
    }

    public static void UseHttClientMapGet(this IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/client1", async context =>
        {
            var service = context.RequestServices!.GetRequiredService<Service1>();
            var r1 = await service.GetAsync();
            // note: context.RequestServices will be marked as disposed in debugger
            var service2 = context.RequestServices!.GetRequiredService<Service1>();
            var r2 = await service2.GetAsync();
            var r = r1 + r2;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(r);
        });
    }

    public static void UseCustomContentType(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value != null && context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith("/someEndpoint"))
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }, 0);
            next(context);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
}

public class Service1
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public Service1(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<string?> GetAsync()
    {
        // note: these calls lead to the problem
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("client1");
        var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync("/index");
        return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

In the main program this can be used to enrich the program:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHttpClientExperiment();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttClientMapGet();
app.MapGet("/index", () => "test");
app.UseCustomContentType();
app.Run();
```

Calling `/client1` causes an expected exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
Object name: 'Collection'.
```

If the _httpClientFactory.CreateClient does not create a client that is then used to call httpClient.GetAsync, the  problem does not appear. Notice that when trying to call `var service2 = context.RequestServices(...)`, `context.RequestServices` has been flagged as disposed. If this line is moved before `var r1 = await service.GetAsync()`, it is not yet disposed and succeeds.

How can I use my scoped service with an httpClientFactory without it disposing my context elsewhere?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's happening here. Request services is disposed when the request is over. The HttpClient factory doesn't affect it in anyway, it creates its own scope. Are you missing code?

Comment: No, when trying to obtain service2 in MapGet (after r1 and the note), a "has been disposed" exception occurs before the get request is over. My expectation is that this should not happen. And if the http client factory is not used, this does not happen. I don't know why.

Comment: I added a complete program start and I missed a method UseCustomContentType, which I thought was unrelated, as it was set on another endpoint.

Comment: Also note, the exception is not logged, I hit it with an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Oh I think I might have gotten it: In the middleware, I have to return  next(context). Then the exception might not occur.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I had this middleware:

```cs
app.Use((context, next) => {
    // ...
    next(context);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

But intead it should have been like this:

```cs
app.Use((context, next) => {
    // ...
    return next(context);
});
```

Somehow the problem only manifested when I used the httpClientFactory and was not a problem before.

Maybe an expert can shed some light on why this is. But it seems that the problem does not occur with this fixed middleware.

In any case, I also recommend this [article](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/).

Comment: This finally makes sense now. When you don't await or return the task then the pipeline server has no idea that your asynchronous code is still running. That's why it disposed the  request services.